# Throwing custom exception from Jackson Serializer in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I was wondering if anyone could help - I am writing a custom Json serializer, extending from JsonSerializer, and I want to wrap any exceptions that could be thrown in my own custom exception, extended from IOException. However, whenever I run any unit tests (using junit) to confirm that the exception is thrown it is failing, saying that -

```
Expected: (exception with message a string containing "Unable to serialize!" and an instance of com.cybersource.profile.serializer.MySerializerException)
 got: <com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected IOException (of type com.cybersource.profile.serializer.MySerializerException): Unable to serialize!>
```

Any idea how to get around this, or is it not possible to throw a custom exception?

Comment: You will have to provide us the code.

Comment: Without your Junit code, we really can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted - turns out for a custom exception you shouldn't extend from IOException, but JsonProcessingException!

Comment: Depends: `IOException`s can be thrown, but benefit of `JsonProcessingException` is that they will get wrapped with extra information, whereas `IOException`s will just be propagated as is (since they are assumed to be "real" low-level I/O problems). So you are probably better of throwing JPEs, agreed.